# How to navigate to a lightning page tab without using navigateToURL

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

On click of a button we want to navigate to a lightning page. This can be done using navigateToURL but the URL here can become dynamic and cause issues like 'Paage not found' error.

Ex: If in a sandbox org, user creates a new lightning page tab(Tab B), gives source as our lightning page(TestLightningPage), but gives the name and label as something different(Name : ObjectB ; Label  ObjectB).

Due to change in '**name**', the URL that is generated will change.

> Old URL : https://myDomain-dev.lightning.force.com/one/one.app#/n/ObjectA
>
> New URL : https://userDomain-sandbox.lightning.force.com/one/one.app#/n/ObjectB

Causing page not found error.

> Code Used for navigating to URL:

```
 var namespace = component.get('v.namespace');
    var urlEvent = $A.get( "e.force:navigateToURL" );
    if(namespace === 'c')
        var url = '/one/one.app#/n/ObjectA';
    else
        var url = '/one/one.app#/n/' + namespace +'__ObjectA';
    urlEvent.setParams({ "url":  url});
    urlEvent.fire( );
```

What can be solution to this? I want something like navigateToLightningPage which will eradicate hardcoding object name in code.

Comment: What do you mean by Lightning page can be renamed, Visualforce page is renamed and you would need to dynamically refer to the new page?

Comment: @RahulSharma : I have updated the question.

Comment: What is functionality of your lightning component?

Comment: @RahulSharma :  There is a component that displays information about custom object(ObjectA). On click of delete, this object is deleted from DB and user is to be navigated to above tab.